# How to use @JsonTypeInfo, @JsonSubType to determine a field type based on a sibling field's value?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

Say I have a class structure like this :-

```
class ShapeRequest {

    ShapeInfo shapeInfo;
    Shape shape;

    static class ShapeInfo {
        String shapeName;
        String shapeDimension;
    }

    static abstract class Shape {

    }

    static class Square extends Shape{
        int area;
    }

    static class Circle extends Shape{
        int area;
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize the ShapeRequest in a way that field **shape**, is mapped to Square or Circle type, depending on the **shapeInfo.shapeName** field value?

For example, the following JSON should map to ShapeRequest with Circle shape type, because shapeInfo.shapeName = "circle"

```
{
  "shapeInfo": {
    "shapeName": "circle",
    "shapeDimension": "2"
  },
  "shape": {
    "area": 10
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it below:

```
public class JsonTypeExample {

    // Main method to test our code.
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // json to circle based on shapeName
        String json = "{\"shapeName\":\"circle\",\"area\":10}";
        Shape shape = objectMapper.readerFor(Shape.class).readValue(json);
        System.out.println(shape.getClass());
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(shape));

        // json to square based on shapeName
        json = "{\"shapeName\":\"square\",\"area\":10}";
        shape = objectMapper.readerFor(Shape.class).readValue(json);
        System.out.println(shape.getClass());
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(shape));
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "shapeName")
    @JsonSubTypes({
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Square.class, name = "square"),
            @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
    })
    static class Shape {
        Shape() {
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeName("square")
    static class Square extends Shape {
        public int area;

        Square(int area){
            super();
            this.area = area;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeName("circle")
    static class Circle extends Shape {
        public int area;

        Circle(int area){
            super();
            this.area = area;
        }
    }
}
```

Here Shape class is annotated with JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes.

> @JsonTypeInfo is used to indicate details of type information which is to be included in serialization and de-serialization.
> Here *property* signifies the value to be considered for determining the SubType.

> @JsonSubTypes is used to indicate subtypes of types annotated.
> Here *name* and *value* maps the shapeName to appropriate SubType class.

Whenever a JSON is passed as in the example, de-serialization happens via JsonSubTypes, then it gives back the appropriate JAVA object based on *shapeName*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, you're missing out the whole point of deserializing to class ShapeRequest {} which contains shapeInfo and the actual shape

Comment: Can you share an example of how you want to serialize/de-serialize the ShapeRequest?

Comment: Looks like you are not framing the problem statement right. Its not ideal to keep type signifier in a different place. Try to move that within shape.

Comment: Yeah. But Unfortunately, that's how it comes from an external system.

Comment: I tried a lot to achieve what you are looking for but it seems impossible. You can max set the shape to circle/square but can't set the area. This can be achieved using explicit mapper:

new ObjectMapper().readerFor(Shape.class)
                        .readValue(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
                                ImmutableMap.of("shapeName", shapeInfo.getShapeName(), "area", 0))).. This should be called within shapeInfo setter and ignore shape setter within ShapeRequest. I feel this is not easily achievable as the problem statement is against what JsonSubTypes support.

Comment: One last suggestion, copying the shapeName inside shape as well, will solve your problem. 
Then you Java object will look like this - ShapeRequest(shapeInfo=ShapeInfo(shapeName=circle, shapeDimension=2), shape=Circle(area=10)).

Comment: Thank you for your time Suman. However I have no control over the request Json. As of now, i am manually traversing the shapeInfo JsonNode and then casting the shape depending on what i find in the node.